# Translation from English in to Armenian

Tags: translation

"There is currently no active translator for this translation, please consider becoming a translator as your suggestion might otherwise remain unreviewed". i see this message in top of the window while suggesting a translations so can you please help me to figure out how to became a translator?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can start contributing your translations here:

https://l10n.elementary.io

Comment: I've already did that. I just don't want my translation suggestions remain unreviewed.